# Extending Jquery plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to extend jQuery form plugin inside my plugin. I have written code below but I am getting infinite loop in `submitHandler`.

What is wrong in my code? How can I fix it?

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({ 
    //plugin name - myvalidateform
    myvalidate: function(options) { 
      //Settings list and the default values
      var defaults = {     
        relues:null,
        url:null,
        password:0,
        type:'get',
        ajax:null
      };     
      var o2 = $.extend(defaults, options);         
      return this.each(function() {        
        var o =o2;
        var obj = $(this);                   
        var formplugin= $(obj).validate({
          submitHandler: function(form) {
          alert("a");
         $(form).submit();
      }
      });          

      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The validator overrides the submit, so you're just calling the submit the validator just attached to.

Try changing this (in the validator):

```
validator.settings.submitHandler.call( validator, validator.currentForm );
if (validator.submitButton) {
// and clean up afterwards; thanks to no-block-scope, hidden can be referenced
    hidden.remove();
}
return false;
```

to:

```
if (validator.submitButton) {
// and clean up afterwards; thanks to no-block-scope, hidden can be referenced
    hidden.remove();
}
return validator.settings.submitHandler.call( validator, validator.currentForm ) ? true : false;
```

Now if you want to submit you should be able to use "return true" on your submitHandler to submit the form.  Now it's possible I made a mistake and there's a better way to do it, but at least I've some answer that may work.

Also check my website for jQuery plugin development guides if you like.

Comment: I don't think that is issue because you I use directly validation plugin it works with submit handler

Comment: Of course it works with the submit handler, but the validation is called on submit.  That's how your loop is created.

Like I said, I could be wrong with that being the correct solution to the issue, but the reasoning behind how your loop is happening should be correct.

I don't have any other suggestions from looking at the code, you can try what I suggested and check if it works or you can keep looking for another solution which I don't have for you.

Hope everything works out, good luck man! :)